# Fazer um ImageView piscar

Tags: android

Meu app tem um `ImagemView` e eu estou querendo fazer ele piscar. 
Este método fica repetindo por 6 segundos.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    verificarAndamento();

    if(emCaputura){
        Log.e("Tempo" , ""+tempoDecorrido);
        if(tempoDecorrido % 1000==0){
            imagem.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            //Toast.makeText(this, "1000", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }else if(tempoDecorrido % 500==0){
            imagem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

          //Toast.makeText(this, "500", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }//Jeito que tentei fazer repedir

        synchronized (this) {
            long current_time = event.timestamp;

            curX = event.values[0];
            curY = event.values[1];
            curZ = event.values[2];

            if (prevX == 0 && prevY == 0 && prevZ == 0) {
                last_update = current_time;
                last_movement = current_time;
                prevX = curX;
                prevY = curY;
                prevZ = curZ;
            }

            long time_difference = current_time - last_update;
            if (time_difference > 0) {
                float movement = Math.abs((curX + curY + curZ) - (prevX - prevY - prevZ)) / time_difference;
                int limit = 1500;
                float min_movement = 1E-6f;
                if (movement > min_movement) {
                    if (current_time - last_movement >= limit) {   
                        movements.add(movement);
                    }
                    last_movement = current_time;
                }
                prevX = curX;
                prevY = curY;
                prevZ = curZ;
                last_update = current_time;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Quero que a imagem fique piscando enquanto o método estiver rodando.

Comment: Este "medo"?!?!?!

Comment: era pra ser metodo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use isso:

flicker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha android:duration="500" android:repeatCount="infinite" android:repeatMode="reverse" android:fromAlpha="0.5" android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

No código, faça isso:

```
imageView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.flicker));
```

Configure quantas vezes deseja repetir a animação. No caso, está `android:repeatCount="infinite"`

Como você deseja por 6 segundos, coloque em`android:duration="6000 "`

Comment: Colocar este xml em qual pasta no projeto?

Comment: Você deve criar uma pasta "anim" dentro da pasta "res".
Coloque o arquivo dentro de "res/anim"

Comment: Muito obrigado funcionou

Comment: Por nada, marque como resposta por favor ;)

Comment: ok. só mais uma duvida , eu em troquei a duração e ela mesmo assim não parou , eu tenho um eu uso o método onStop() , tem como eu parar essa animação la dentro?

Comment: Não, troque o android:repeatCount para 10 , 20, 30 vezes se for o caso, mas qualquer coisa diferente de infinite